# what will be the alternative for Pdfstamper in itext7?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, itext7

I tried to find the alternative for Pdfstamper in itext7 but didn't get how to use? I've already implemented code in itextshap its working but not in itext7.

I've one more doubt what will be the alternative for Acro Fields in itext7?

public byte[] GeneratePDF(string pdfPath, Dictionary<string, string> formFieldMap, bool formFlattening = true)

```
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
       //PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

        var formFields = stamper.AcroFields;

        foreach (var fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
            formFields.SetField(fieldName, formFieldMap[fieldName]);

        stamper.FormFlattening = formFlattening;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You're asking about the *"alternative for Pdfstamper in itext7"* but you already have it in your code, `PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer)`.

Comment: i tried but its not wokring shwoing some errors like -- can not convert form System.IO.MemoryStream to iText.Kernel.Pdf.DocumentProperites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iText API got completely overhauled between versions 5.x and 7.x. Thus, you do not always have a one-to-one correspondence between classes here and there. Thus, I would propose studying the [introductory ebooks](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks) on the iText knowledge base site before porting code.

There actually is an example in those ebooks very similar to your code:

```c#
//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("name", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("James Bond");
fields.TryGetValue("language", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("English");
fields.TryGetValue("experience1", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("Off");
fields.TryGetValue("experience2", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("Yes");
fields.TryGetValue("experience3", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("Yes");
fields.TryGetValue("shift", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("Any");
fields.TryGetValue("info", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("I was 38 years old when I became an MI6 agent.");

form.FlattenFields();
pdf.Close();
```

*(["Flattening a Form"](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-4-making-a-pdf-interactive-net#Chapter4:MakingaPDFinteractive%7C.NET-Flatteningaform) in "Chapter 4: Making a PDF interactive | .NET" of "iText 7: Jump-Start Tutorial for .NET")*